# Javascript detect current page and change hyperlink color

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have the javascript below to detect what page URL I'm in and change the hyperlink color
with CSS class named 'current'.

However it can't detect subpages like https://stackoverflow.com/product/javascript, javascript is the subpage of product, so when I'm in javascript page, product hyperlink menu should be enable with 'current' CSS class.

```
$(function(){
      $('a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
          $(this).addClass('current');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you print to log(`console.log`) the values of each. You have to make sure that the links have `http://www.theFullUrl/subpage` because `window.location.href` returns something like that.

Answer (score 1):

for each link, you would like to see if the href is a base of the current page

```
$(function(){
  var windowHref = window.location.href;

  $('a').each(function(index) {
    var linkHref = $(this).prop('href');
    // assume "home" is the first link
    if (index === 0) {
      if (windowHref === linkHref) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
      }
    } else if (windowHref.indexOf(linkHref) === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why did you use `===0` instead of `==0`?

Comment: This is the strict (and slightly faster) way to compare homogeneous stuff, unless you intend to compare apples to oranges (or strings to numbers) :) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators for the reference.

Comment: @tommyTheHitMan This doesn't work with homepage link. Whichever page I go the homepage menu link is with 'current' class.

Comment: @Rapide you haven't provided any context, but I'm assuming by home page you mean yourdomain.com.  by your definition of 'base page', yes, the home page is a base of every page in the domain.  are you trying to highlight every page except the index?

Comment: @tommyTheHitMan I wanted to highlight the homepage link also. But whenever I'm in other page for example product page, the homepage link was with current class. How to add this exception when I'm in other page homepage link wasn't highlighted, but when I'm at the homepage, it is highlighted.

Comment: my guess is that all of your homepage links include 'index.html' or 'index.php', so "yourdomain.com/index.php".indexOf("yourdomain.com/sub/other.html") is not 0.